# How to set up GRUB2 password in an easy way?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, password, bootloader

I need to setup password for GRUB2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64. **The setup I am trying to reach is to have [e]dit and [c]onsole options protected by password, but booting of operating system entries (Ubuntu, Windows) unprotected.**

I have studied [Grub2/Passwords](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) (it is outdated, quite chaotic and hardly readable by the way) and it seems that I need to set up the superuser password and add `--unrestricted` option to menu entries. OK, but where exactly do I have add this `--unrestricted` option?

If in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` then it is not the most clever idea, because this file is overwritten each time `grub-update` is run. So this is not an option for me, because - let's assume that - I like to change GRUB background image twice a week. Moreover, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` readability is far from perfect; it is still not obvious where to put the `--unrestricted` option.

If in the menu entry files in the`/etc/grub.d/*`, then it is even worse than editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Those files are quite a mess in the terms of readability so editing them is all the more difficult.

Is there any clean and easy method of setting GRUB2 password up as I described? Maybe some brilliant documentation other than the one I linked in this post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to password protect Grub menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/656206/how-to-password-protect-grub-menu)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the section on protecting entries](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords#Adding_Protection_to_Ubuntu_Entries):

> There is currently no automated method of adding users or designating menu items to be protected. The user must manually edit the GRUB 2 scripts. The GRUB 2 menu is a compilation of the inputs of several scripts. The /etc/grub.d/10_linux file is responsible for adding the default Ubuntu OS to the GRUB 2 menu. [...] The majority of these sections are devoted to editing the default scripts located in the /etc/grub.d/ folder.

And in [the next section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords#Adding_Protection_to_Other_Entries):

> The GRUB 2 menu includes selections for operating systems other than the default Ubuntu OS via the /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober script. [...] This would include other Ubuntu and Linux installations, Windows, etc.
>
> The 30_os-prober script looks for specific types of operating systems. The user can make the changes for all of the OS's via a single command, or individually by OS type as documented below.

So, it seems you will have to edit the files in `/etc/grub.d/`. At least for adding a superuser, you needn't edit one of those files, but can create a [new file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords#Setting_Up_Password_Protection):

> The superuser/user information and password do not have to be contained in the /etc/grub.d/00_header file. The information can be placed in any /etc/grub.d file as long as that file is incorporated into grub.cfg. The user may prefer to enter this data into a custom file, such as /etc/grub.d/40_custom so it is not overwritten should the Grub package be updated. If placing the information in a custom file, do not include the "cat << EOF" and "EOF" lines as the content is automatically added from these files.

These paragraphs remain relevant until the official GRUB documentation says otherwise:

> The grub-mkconfig program does not yet have built-in support for generating configuration files with authentication.

(Whatever that's supposed to mean.)

---

## Up to Ubuntu 12.04

Here are the outdated instructions for protecting menu entries:

> In /etc/grub.d/10_linux, find the following line:
>
> ```
> printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"
> ```
>
> Add `--users ''` :
>
> ```
> printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} --users '' {\n" "${os}" "${version}"
> ```

For all the entries in `30_os-prober`:

```
sudo sed 's/--class os /--class os --users /' -i /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

[Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com) doesn't list Ubuntu 12.10, so I am not sure if 12.10 uses the old method or the new one.

## Ubuntu 13.04 and later

Now, the `10_linux` file uses `echo` instead of `printf`:

```
echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

And the `30_os-prober` file uses `cat` and heredocs:

```
# The minix entry
cat << EOF
menuentry "${LONGNAME} (on ${DEVICE}, Multiboot)" {
EOF
# The hurd entry
cat << EOF
menuentry '$(echo "${LONGNAME} $onstr" | grub_quote)' --class hurd --class gnu --class os \$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnuhurd-/boot/gnumach.gz-false-$(grub_get_device_id "${DEVICE}")' {
EOF
```

So you can stick the `--user ""` part somewhere before the menuentry ends (before the brace opens).

Remember to backup any files you modify, and run `update-grub` after modification.

Comment: Well, that's why a posted my question... The community documentation You have quoted is definitely not up to date. Content of file /etc/grub.d/10_linux in Ubuntu 14.04 is different than stated there, so the instruction is useless.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki since you linked to wrong page, it seemed to me you hadn't read the page with any seriousness.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki here, I updated to reflect changes in the grub.d files.

Comment: You are right, I pasted the wrong URL! I have just corrected it, thanks for pointing out. Now I am going to try your updated instruction. No response from me within an hour definitely means that my PC exploded and we are both burning.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki if it does work, could you update the community wiki?

Comment: It does not work. I tried the '--unrestricted' option in various places, but the only result I get is unbootable menu entry. I withdrew the '-1' since You updated your answer, but my problem is still not resolved - please read the bold part of my question. After all, it looks like GRUB2 is a piece of turd - unfinished and undocumented software.

Answer (score 0):

Configure `superusers`. To do this, for example, add the following lines to `/etc/grub.d/00_header`:

```
# Support user protection on entries
cat << EOF
set superusers="admin"
password_pbkdf2 admin grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.8E51188BE7DF732DDF102C918DEC152087558E04DA843B4A74C3EA8374BAB1ECA493399D62E3F2779F55C5BE2E8B65B8636113A99C09BFB892DB64626337904C.3016474FE6B420DBE6371B41D9BE8471B135CDF4BE674AC1265D3BA123CD9E459E960AEC199AB8C7C1C1A6BAF45314C64591E85E404AB54F4777E032A50CC731
EOF
```

Update the encrypted password using the output of `grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` command. In our example, what you need to change is the following information:

```
grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.8E51188BE7DF732DDF102C918DEC152087558E04DA843B4A74C3EA8374BAB1ECA493399D62E3F2779F55C5BE2E8B65B8636113A99C09BFB892DB64626337904C.3016474FE6B420DBE6371B41D9BE8471B135CDF4BE674AC1265D3BA123CD9E459E960AEC199AB8C7C1C1A6BAF45314C64591E85E404AB54F4777E032A50CC731
```

Edit the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file and look for line 129 (in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). In its pristine form, it should look like the following:

```
echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id'     {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

Here, add the `--unrestricted` option after the CLASS variable to complete the configuration line:

```
echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --unrestricted \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

Rebuild `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. To do this you run the `sudo update-grub` command.

Reboot the system and try.

Now you should have a configuration where:

- The main Ubuntu operating system entry will boot up normally but no one except the `superusers` will be able to edit the related entry in the list.
- Only the `superusers` will be able to boot and edit all other entries in the list.

---

See also:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-GRUB_2_Password_Protection.html