# Grub2: Setting password in version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1

Tags: 14.04, grub2, grubrescue

I am using `ubuntu 14.04` and the Grub version is `2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1`. I've been trying this for a long time. I saw this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499264/how-to-set-up-grub2-password-in-an-easy-way) but couldn’t get it work that way. Anyway I have the solution but am not sure if it is correct or if it has any **security risks**. Please suggest.

I wanted to configure GRUB such that:-

1. Authentication is required to edit the grub menu or enter rescue mode.
2. Authentication is **not** required to boot the OS

I followed the [Ubuntu Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) and also many other blogs but all are based on GRUB2 versions older than `2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1` so the grub script cannot be edited as suggested in the docs. Following the docs I tried to edit menuentries but each time the issue faced was that: `Authentication was needed to boot the OS too`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking help from [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499264/how-to-set-up-grub2-password-in-an-easy-way) and the [Ubuntu Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) I managed to get what I wanted but please suggest if I am correct, if my configurations are really secure. Mainly that when a new kernel is installed, the GRUB configuration will also have to be edited or not.

**1. Create hashed password**

> grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2

Give your password and you will recieve the hash.

**2. Create GRUB Authentication**

In the File /etc/grub.d/40_custom add these entries at the end, where

```
set superusers="user1" 
password_pbkdf2 user1 GIVE-GRUB-PASSWORD-HASH-HERE
export superusers
```

replace GIVE-GRUB-PASSWORD-HASH-HERE with the hash of the password received as the output of `grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` .

**3. Apply Authentication to menuentries in the file /etc/grub.d/10_linux**

Add `--users ''` to the following lines such that you have:-

```
echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --users '' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

and

```
echo "submenu '$(gettext_printf "Advanced options for %s" "${OS}" | grub_quote)' --users ''  \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id' {"
```

Add `--unrestricted` to the following line such that you have:-

```
echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --unrestricted \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

**4. Update Grub**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Edit**

**5. Reboot System**

Forgot to add this earlier; you need the reboot the system after that.

```
sudo reboot
```