# If I have disable recovery option and someone still get's to root using the ro recovery nomodeset how do I password protect root?

Tags: boot, root, recovery-mode

If I have disable recovery option and someone still get's to root using the ro recovery nomodeset how do I password protect root? I know how to block the recovery just Want it to require a password every time you use a command in root

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up GRUB2 password in an easy way?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/499264/how-to-set-up-grub2-password-in-an-easy-way)

Comment: AFIK physical access is root access as you can always boot a live usb and access the hard drive. IMO the best option is full encryption (LUKS) or at least encrypt any sensitive data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that is was really simple, all you have to do is run the following command and it adds a password to root.`sudo passwd root`.