# How i lock Recovery Mode in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: data-recovery, lock, mode

I want it so that when anybody tries to edit my Ubuntu in recovery mode, then it is required to give the password to edit this:

Example  of recovery mode entry:
[image]

Comment: Ok, there's quite a lot of computer security questions....

Comment: @Ravan - that link was helpful u know

Answer (score 1):

You can [add a password to the grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656206/how-to-password-protect-grub-menu) - but another issue is that a attacker could also boot from a Live CD or similar, and pretty much do the same stuff as if they had access to recovery mode

So I would recommend setting a power-on BIOS password if you can (this depends on your hardware), so on boot (before it even gets to Grub), it will show a password prompt. This can be worked-around on some machines by resetting bits of hardware, but it still make life more difficult for attackers.

Also note, as discussed in the comments below [this post on resetting the admin password](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/178596) that having physical access to the machine means that a attacker can use various ways to circumvent security such as passwords by simply taking the machine apart. If you believe such security for your data on the computer is necessary, full-disk encryption or a similar may be the way to go - though if you need to recover the data in the event of some software/hardware failure this may make it difficult/impossible.

To find out some of the extremes of protection you can use, try [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/676545/178596).

Comment: Apparently you understand the question (I don't). Could you edit it into something that makes sense?

Comment: @TRiG - I think the user is referring to the entry you get in the Grub menu on boot that allows you to reset the password etc - edited.